# Why did WW1 soldiers carry so much equipment?

Tags: world-war-one

I am actually so confused. Shouldn’t they just carry a gun and ammo and maybe some rations?

Comment: Whose soldiers? In what circumstances? On which front?

Comment: If you got sent onto a battlefield to fight for months, would you just want a gun and a can of food?

Comment: You need, at the very least, a change of clothing, something to bivoac with -- i.e. (parts of) a tent, a sleeping bag, something to cook with (stove, cans), and rations -- gas protection, helmet, a spade, coat for cold weather / rain, water, ammo, your rifle, and a first aid kit. (Just raffling off what I remember lugging around on *my* time in the army.) That's not including any special equipment -- radio, mortar rounds, belt ammo for the MG, ... -- You might get lucky and get a truck you can toss all that kit on. If you aren't lucky, you've got to carry that and march 30km+ / day.

Comment: Soldiers today often carry more than 45kg so WW1 soldiers had it easy by comparison!

Comment: @DevSolar This could be an answer

Comment: I served in the army. On a simple overnight exercise you carry a lot of stuff with you. Compared to real combat, a very light load. We didn't carry live ammo, for example. Rarely blanks. Often no food, as it was only for one night. Even so, I think we lugged at least 15-20 kg or more.

Comment: Difficult to answer unless there is a reference to the equipment they carried.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: I updated my answer to assume "an average soldier".

Answer (score 4):

The weight (an average) soldier carries has increased from World War I. If you look at the respective article for the equipment of a World War I soldier, you can ask yourself which items you consider dispensable.

This article probably gives what an average British soldier carried in World War I:

- https://www.thehistorypress.co.uk/articles/a-british-soldier-s-kit-in-the-first-world-war/

Over the centuries, the equipment has looked like this (there is also World War I British equipment displayed):

- http://www.abroadintheyard.com/thousand-years-of-kit-inspections-images-of-soldiers-personal-equipment-from-1066-to-2014/

Today's problems with overweight:

- https://mwi.usma.edu/the-overweight-infantryman/
- https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/188986/British-soldiers-suffer-injuries-from-too-heavy-weights

And what the Romans carried:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_military_personal_equipment

The solution for the modern problems seem to be along these lines:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_exoskeleton